# highcharts: issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm making an app with highcharts, after having many problems I finally make plotted but now takes the correct data but I need to make some adjustments.

for example if an user registers a new log on the same day it should take the cost of the log and add it to the logs of the same day or simply show if there are no more, I follow the [railcast episode 223](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts?view=asciicast) and helpme a little. but my issue is: when I add a new log it create a new bar:
(there are only 2 logs, I'm gonna create a new log)
[image]
here is that my app do.
[image]

also I need to fix the datetime, here is my code:

```
    $(function () {
      new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo: 'foo_chart',defaultSeriesType: 'column' },
        title: { text: 'tanking costs daily' },
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
        yAxis: {
          title: { text: 'cost' }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e %Y", this.x) + ': ' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Days',
          pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>, 
          pointStart: <%= 1.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
          data:[
            <% for tankinglog in @tankinglog  %>
              <%= "(" + tankinglog.cost.to_f.round(2).to_s + "),"%>
            <% end %>
          ]
        }]
      });
    });
```

if you see the list on the picture I have 3 logs...the last 2 logs have the same date these must appear in the same bar with the sum of their costs

Comment: How are you getting the data? What does your series look like? Do you want to only show all logs made on Day1 or do you want to show what time on Day1 each log was made?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing. You want all the data summed into one bar? A new bar is created for each number you have in the `data` list. So your for-each loop is creating a new bar for each item in `@tankinglog`. The solution is to sum what's required into one number, then add it to the list.

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking because your question is poor but here are all the values summed into one bar.

```
$(function () {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: 'foo_chart',defaultSeriesType: 'column' },
    title: { text: 'tanking costs daily' },
    xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
    yAxis: {
      title: { text: 'cost' }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e %Y", this.x) + ': ' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Days',
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>, 
      pointStart: <%= 1.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
      data:[
        <% 
        result = 0;
        for tankinglog in @tankinglog 
            result += tankinglog.cost.to_f
        end %>
        <%= result.round(2).to_s %>
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: ok sorry for that question so confused
that's so close that I need,

Comment: what I need is if  one day become more of a log. join these log and displayed on a single bar, so, to show various bars with the total cost of logs per day...again sorry I don't speak english so much

Comment: if you see the list on the picture I have 3 logs...the last 2 logs have the same date these must appear in the same bar with the sum of their costs

Comment: I don't know how your data is organized so I can't provide explicate code for you. However, you should be able to make small modifications to the above code to do what you want.